# conversion backward from mp3 to oma

Tags: mp3, audio-conversion

My wife has a very old Sony walkman which plays audio files in a special format: oma.

The software has stopped working and seems not to be supported by Sony any more.

I thought I might try to convert some files such as mp3 to oma but I am mostly advised to download the Sonicstage software from nonexistent places or hear about conversions from oma to mp3, i.e. the wrong way.

Is there any hope at all for this old player?

Comment: Your time would probably be better spent heading to the local electronics store or Amazon and buying a modern MP3 player, instead of monkeying with Sony's proprietary format they've basically given up on...  :)   For example, Amazon.com has some no-name MP3 players for [LESS THAN A DOLLAR](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank?keywords=mp3+players&fst=as%3Aon&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A172623%2Cn%3A1264866011%2Ck%3Amp3+players&qid=1482957758&sort=price-asc-rank)!

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Less than a dollar... before you buy the micro sd card to store the music on.  (It's not a complete solution, although it works pretty well once you add a cheap card.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ffmpeg

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is usually the best bet when it comes to converting between niche multimedia formats.

Unfortunately, while ffmpeg supports creating ("muxing") OMA containers, it doesn't appear to support encoding the ATRAC audio codec that usually goes inside the container.

> ```
> ffmpeg -formats
> File formats:
>  D. = Demuxing supported
>  .E = Muxing supported
>  --
>  DE oma             Sony OpenMG audio
> ```

> ```
> ffmpeg -codecs
> Codecs:
>  D..... = Decoding supported
>  .E.... = Encoding supported
>  ..V... = Video codec
>  ..A... = Audio codec
>  ..S... = Subtitle codec
>  ...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
>  ....L. = Lossy compression
>  .....S = Lossless compression
>  -------
>  D.A.L. atrac1               ATRAC3 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding)
>  D.A.L. atrac3               ATRAC3 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding 3)
>  D.A.L. atrac3p              ATRAC3 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding 3+) (decoders: atrac3plus )
> ```

---

### atrac3.exe

[atrac3.exe](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/sony_atrac3_audio_codec.htm) is apparently a freeware ATRAC encoder.

I've never used this piece of software before, so although it looks pretty legitimate, I don't know if it's trustworthy.

But it might be your last resort.

---

### Other Formats

You might be able to look up your Walkman on [Sony's Support Site](https://esupport.sony.com/US/product-selection/) to see if it supports other audio formats that ffmpeg can convert to.